# Creating folders based on names in a text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a python script to read a text file that has a list of names in it and create folders based on those names. For example, if the text file has "john_doe" and "jane_doe" in it, the script should create two folders. One called "john_doe" and one called "jane_doe".

When I run my script, I get the error WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or colume label syntax is incorrect: ",open file 'names.txt', mode 'r' at 0X00000000025E6300>"

Here's the script that I'm running:

```
import os

with open('names.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.strip()
        os.mkdir(str(x))
```

I think that it's more of a Windows problem (hence the WindowsError), but I'm not sure how to get around it. Any tips?

Comment: change this with open('names.txt') as x: line as with open('names.txt','r') as x:

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should have done that in the first place. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: os.mkdir(line), not os.mkdir(x), because x is the file descriptor, not the line

Comment: Flagging to close as a problem caused by simple typographical error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        os.mkdir(str(x))
```

You meant:

```
        os.mkdir(str(line))
```

You don't even need `str()`, since `line` is already a `str`. (I suspect you only added it because `os.mkdir(x)` was giving you an error.)

Your previous code was trying to create several directories, all named something like "`<open file 'names.txt', mode 'r' at 0X00000000025E6300>`".

Comment: That worked. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes I guess :). You're right, I added the str because os.mkdir(x) was giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the current working directory by:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

You may find that your program maynot have appropriate permission to make changes on the directory.

Try changing to something else like:

```
>>> os.chdir("<someAbsolutePath>")
```

And if you find the program can write/ make changes on another directory, then you may need to change the permissions of the program.

Comment: Good thought! I already double checked the code with this previously and it didn't matter, so I took it out jus to get rid of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be catching a problem with special characters and whitespace between the names.  Windows doesn't like it when you fail to escape the whitespace between multi-word directory names.

Try (i) reading the lines as Unicode (to avoid special character problems) and then (ii) joining the names with an underscore to avoid whitespace issues:

```
import os

with open('names.txt', 'rU') as x:
    for line in x:
        line = line.strip().split()
        filename = "_".join([i for i in line])
        os.mkdir(filename)
```

Comment: I didn't have to do that in this instance, but I'm absolutely going to keep this in mind for future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# My solution from above...
# Trying to create folders from a file
# By Rob Thomas
# 16/3/2019 Ver 2.0

import os,sys

# Change to correct folder to create files in
# Just copy from Windows Explorer, then add in the extra "\"
os.chdir("R:\\_1 Y9 Yellow")
print(os.getcwd())
right=input("Is this correct? Y/N: ")

if right.lower()!="y":
    print("Exiting...")
    sys.exit()

try:    # Also change to the correct file name 
    with open('Yellow.txt', "r") as x:
        for line in x:
            line = line.strip()
            os.mkdir(str(line))
        x.close()

except OSError:  
    print ("Creation of the directory failed" )
else:  
    print ("Successfully created the directory" )
```